# Logcat not showing logs in android studio

Tags: adb, logcat, android-logcat, android-studio-3.0

Logcat not showing logs when a testing device becomes idle for some time. After each 10-15 min, logcat stops logging logs from the device and I have to do each time disable and enable ADB integration to logcat to work again. How to solve this so that logcat logs continuously?